# Clean install of Spark from source - R doesnt work but Python does

Tags: r

I've just done a clean install of Spark from source on Mac OSx.

I can get pyspark working fine, and it comes out with a lot of `info` as part of the load up, but when I run sparkR `./sparkR`, it doesn't give me anything and just gives me a normal R prompt.

Can anyone provide any pointers on where it may be going wrong? If inside R I try to do: `sc<-sparkR.init()`, I get the error message `could not find function 'sparkR.init'`.

Comment: If that's the only code used in an R console then you forgot to load any packages. If it's not the only code then you forgot to load ... all the code.

Comment: that's the obvious solution, but I was under the impression running the sparkR script/shell was meant to take care of all that for me, and as part of any default build it should load all the packages it needs? If PySpark didnt work then I'd understand it was probably an error on my side, but the fact that Pyspark does work but SparkR doesnt is a bit more confusing?